# position fixed with navigation 100%

Tags: jquery, css, html, position

please help me fixing my inner div or navigation not to expend out of its container. following is my code where i have a container of `64em` and its in the middle of screen. once scroll top my header disappear and navigation will fixed at top 0. but in my case navigation is 100% and it expand to right side.

```
html, body{margin:0; padding:0; width:100%;}
.container{width:64em; margin:0 auto; background:#F5FFDA; position:relative;}
.container header{width:100%; height:80px; background:#EFFDB9;}
.container nav{ display:block; width:100%; height:60px; background:#C5FFF8;}
.container section{height:1200px; background:#FFCC5E;}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var headerheight = $('.container header').height();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > headerheight) {
            $('.container nav').css({position: "fixed", top: "0px", display: "block"});
        } else {
            $('.container nav').css({position: "relative", top: "0px"});
        }
    });
});
```

please advice

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>header</header>
        <div id="content">
            <nav>navigation</nav>
            <section>section</section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check if you have any `margin` or `padding` and you might need to remove it if you are using `width: 100%`.

Comment: no margin or padding

Comment: Try using `left: 0; right: 0;` and remove `width: 100%;`

Comment: I have placed left:0; right:0; and it expend it browser left 0 n right 0 not the container. even my container has position relative.